# Understanding cin.fail() and cin.clear - Vector Appending Program

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, cin

This is my first post to Stack Overflow, please forgive me if I have overlooked any formalities in the following post

I am currently writing a C++ program on Code::Blocks 17.12, using the GNU GCC Compiler. The program is for Exercise P6.4 of Big C++ 2nd Edition where I must write a function to append/combine two vectors worth of users input and then return the vector

I am able to enter the 1st vector just fine, but for some reason it won't allow me to enter the 2nd vector.

I have a feeling that the use of cin.fail() in the while loop is also triggered my 2nd bool value to immediately change to false. For this I added cin.clear(), hoping it would reset the stream to allow for the 2nd vector inputs, but to no avail.

Is it truly cin.fail() causing this error, or is it something else I am overlooking?

Edit: with the use of crtl-z, I am now able to get the 2nd vector, and run the program to completion, though the last element of the first vector a/a_vct is copying twice. Can you point me to some resources on the use of crtl-z to better understand its use? (haven't covered it in the book yet)
ex. if i enter 1 2 3 for a_vct and 1 2 3 for b_vct, c_vct will output 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<double>append(vector<double>a,vector<double>b)
{
    vector<double>c; //combined vct

    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        c.push_back(a[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
    {
        c.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    return c;
};

int main()
{
    vector<double>a_vct; //inputs
    vector<double>b_vct; //inputs
    vector<double>c_vct; //appended vct

    cout<<"Welcome to the vector append-er!"<<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter 1st Vector (enter v to set vector after inputs):"<<endl;
    bool v1_add=true;
    while(v1_add)
    {
        double a;

        cin>>a;
        a_vct.push_back(a);

        if(cin.fail()) //double usage is setting both bools to false???
        {
            v1_add=false;
        }
    }

    cin.clear();

    cout<<"Please enter 2nd Vector. Please enter the same number of elements (enter v to set vector after inputs):"<<endl;
    bool v2_add=true;
    while(v2_add)
    {
        double b;

        cin>>b;
        b_vct.push_back(b);

        if(cin.fail())
        {
            v2_add=false;
        }
    }

    c_vct=append(a_vct,b_vct);

    cout<<"The appended vector is:"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<c_vct.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<c_vct[i]<<" ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: New changes as per the response, works as intended now

```
if(cin.good())
        {
            a_vct.push_back(a);
        }
```

```
if(cin.good())
        {
            b_vct.push_back(b);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After entring the first vector inputs write `Ctrl+Z` (By your keyboard instead of a number) for windows or `Ctrl+D` for linux to make `cin.fail()` be `true` to stop the loop taking inputs and after entring the second vector inputs too.

Note that the vectors will repeat the last entries because you make `push_back(a)` after detecting `cin.fail()`. So, you can avoide that by changing

`a_vct.push_back(a);`

to

`if(cin.good()) a_vct.push_back(a);`

Comment: Thank you! I am now able to enter the second vector. Does crtl-z have any secondary effects aside from clearing cin stream? My function is copying the last element of the first vector (a_vct) twice to the appended vector c_vct

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` is the `EOF` (end of file or end of stream). When the stream reached at it, the `cin.fail()` gives `true`. without it, `cin` waits for another input. I put a note to avoid repeating the last enry.

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer resolves the immediate problem, but...

When you have a failed input, not only do you have to clear the failure flag, you may also have to remove the bad input. If you don't the next read is going to attempt to parse the same bad input and will fail again. Removing a bad input is often done with `std::istream::ignore`. The typical usage

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

removes everything in the stream up to the end of the line. You can replace the `'\n'` with a space, a tab, a comma or any other character that better fits your requirements. Be absolutely certain that you have a bad input, not some other failure case, or you can find yourself removing data that you DO want.

Sidenote:

```
 cin>>b;
 b_vct.push_back(b);
 if(cin.fail())
 {
     v2_add=false;
 }
```

is a bad idea. If `cin>>b;` failed, you don't want to add `b` to the `vector`. You want to make sure `b` is good before adding it.

```
 cin>>b;
 if(cin.fail())
 {
     v2_add=false;
 }
 else
 {
     b_vct.push_back(b);
 }
```

But we can take advantage of `cin >>b;`'s return value and rearrange the logic a bit to make this easier:

```
 if(cin>>b) // if read succeeded
 {
     b_vct.push_back(b); // store
 }
 else
 {
     v2_add=false; // read failed
 }
```

Then, if we take the `while` into account

```
while(v2_add) // loop until failed
{
    if(cin>>b)
    {
        b_vct.push_back(b);
    }
    else
    {
        v2_add=false;
    }
}
```

We see we don't need the `if` at all. It's doing a job that could be done in the `while`'s condition.

```
while(cin>>b) // loop until read fails
{
    b_vct.push_back(b); // store
}
```

And since the only way out of the loop is failure, this is where you place the `clear` and the perhaps an `ignore`

```
while(cin>>b) // loop until read fails
{
    b_vct.push_back(b); // store
}
// Check for EOF here if appropriate
cin.clear(); // clear error flag
// discard invalid input if appropriate
// cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // discard up to end of line
```

If you have a wide variety of possible characters separating inputs, it is often easier (but slower) to read the offending token into a `std::string` and ignore the result.

```
cin.clear(); // clear error flag
std::string discard;
cin >> discard; // discard whatever follows
```

Comment: Thank you, @NarishSingh , but please put the checkmark back on the other answer because this is just a supplementary-sort-of answer. anonymous better addresses the problem you asked about.

Comment: done, will keep this in mind on future posts. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thank you and no worries